# How to hold frame in video render

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes, video, timeline

The cube is not moving for the first 30 frames so I want to render only 1 frame of those and then hold the rest 29 frames and then the cube will start moving after frame 60 to frame 90

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you want the cube to stay still from frame 1 to 60 then it moves from frame 60 to 90? It's not clear what you want... Also, what do you mean by "video render"?

Comment: I want it to stay still from frame 30 to 60, I use 30 as the starting point so if I bake physics they have some time to drop, and I don't know how to say video render any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, hopefully you are rendering to an image sequence instead of to mp4, that is the recommended practice for several reasons.

1. Render the first "hold" image and save as a png.
2. Render frames 60-90, or the "motion" in your scene to image sequence (0060.png - 0090.png)
3. Open a new instance of Blender in Video Editing mode.
4. Add your single "hold" image to the timeline with Add -> Image/Sequence.  You can grab the ends of the clip on the timeline to extend or shorten the number of frames it will be shown.
5. Use Add -> Image/Sequence again to add frames 60-90 all at once, which will add it to the timeline as an image sequence with one image per frame.

Use the timeline to arrange things to your liking.

[image]

Then render this timeline to mp4 using the Output panel.